# building a dynamic where clause in model with ruby, iterating over activerecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model with an has_many association: **Charts** has_many **ChartConditions**

charts model has fields for:

- name (title)
- table_name (model)

The chart_conditions model has fields for

- assoc_name (to .joins)
- name (column)
- value (value)
- operator (operator

Basically my Chart tells us which model (using the table_name field) I want to run a dynamic query on. Then the chart_conditions for the Chart will tell us which fields in that model to sort on.

So In my models that will be queried, i need to dynamically build a where clause using multiple chart_conditions.

Below you can see that i do a joins first based on all the object's assoc_name fields

Example of what I came up with. This works, but not with a dynamic operator for the name/value and also throws a deprecation warning.

```
  def self.dynamic_query(object)
    s = joins(object.map{|o| o.assoc_name.to_sym})

    #WORKS BUT GIVES DEPRECATED WARNING (RAILS4)
    object.each do |cond|
      s = s.where(cond.assoc_name.pluralize.to_sym => {cond.name.to_sym => cond.value})
    end
  end
```

How can i then add in my dynamic operator value to this query? Also why can I not say:

```
s = s.where(cond.assoc_name.pluralize : {cond.name : cond.value})
```

I have to use the => and .to_sym to get it to work. The above syntax errors: **syntax error, unexpected ':' ...ere(cond.assoc_name.pluralize : {cond.name : cond.value}) ... ^**

Answer (score 2):

What if you store the query in a variable and append to that?

```
def self.dynamic_query(object)
  q = joins(object.map{|o| o.assoc_name.to_sym})
  object.each do |cond|
    q = q.where(cond.assoc_name.pluralize : {cond.name : cond.value})
  end
  q # returns the full query
end
```

Another approach might be the `merge(other)` method. From the [API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge):

> Merges in the conditions from other, if other is an ActiveRecord::Relation. Returns an array representing the intersection of the resulting records with other, if other is an array.
>
> ```
> Post.where(published: true).joins(:comments).merge( Comment.where(spam: false) )
> # Performs a single join query with both where conditions.
> ```

That could be useful to knot all the conditions together.

Comment: if i use **scoped = scoped.where(cond.assoc_name.pluralize.to_sym => {cond.name.to_sym => cond.value})** it works, but rails console tells me its deprecated. If i use **scoped = scoped.where(cond.assoc_name.pluralize : {cond.name : cond.value})** it errors. Also, any idea how i would do a dynamic operator for the name : value, so i could use my dynamic operator from my table column>